# Silverlight client port check

Tags: silverlight, tcp, connection, port

I'm facing a problem that gives me a quite hard time ...

> People having trouble to execute a program that needs specific ports to be open, sadly they don't know if its a clientside problem caused by blocked ports, of it its simply a software problem.
>
> So I thought about making a program that checks if the user can access the provided ports, after I made the WPF application, I was thinking about having an easier access to such functionality and tried to produce a Silverlight Version.

Questions:

**a.)** Is there even a way to check if the user can connect to specific ports that aren't in the range of 4502 - 4534 within a silverlight application that runs as plugin in the web browser ?

b.) Is there a way to do this, even without having access to the specific server to provide a policy file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to do it from the in-browser application that its a no. Trusted silverlight application should be able to connect to any port without restrictions.